# Не могу понять как вызываются методы суперкласса в анонимном подклассе

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Дан код:

```
public class Solution {
    private String name;

    Solution(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void sout() {
        new Solution("sout") {
            void printName() {
                System.out.println(getName());
            }
        }.printName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution("main").sout();
    }
}
```

Который работает вполне логично и выводит `"main"`, но если изменить метод `printName()` в анонимном классе, добавив ключевое слово `super` перед вызовом метода `getName()`, то результат вывода будет `"sout"`.

```
void printName() {
                System.out.println(super.getName());
            }
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь `private` методы как и поля класса не виртуальные, почему в методе суперкласса используется переменная подкласса?

Answer (score 1):

У вас нету переменных в подклассе. Вы пользуетесь переменной суперкласса. Когда вы вызываете метод `sout()`, то зоздается новый экземпляр, который возвращает значение из метода суперкласса `getName()`.

То есть вы расширяете класс `Solution` анонимным классом, а в нем нет метода `getName()` поэтому его вывызов происходит в контексте `main` и печатается соответствующее значение экземпляра класса.

С другой стороны `super.getName()` говорит о том, что вызов метода происходит в контексте `sout` и печатается соответствующее значение второго экземпляра класса.